# Why is terser not converting ES6 Template Literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, terser

How to configure terser to convert ES6 Template Literals to ES5 Strings?

I have a file

```
console.log(`Hello World`);
```

Which when I compress with `terser file.js`, the content remains the same.
I would expect to get something like

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Comment: Why specifically is this what you expect? The double-quote string is not smaller, so there isn't any reason for Terser to make this conversion.

Comment: try this, `terser --compress -- file.js`, works for me

Comment: You need a transpiler (e.g. Babel or Traceur).  Terser is just about making the code smaller.